# Use of undeclared type 'UITableViewCell' (WatchKit) iOS

Tags: xcode, uitableview, watchkit

I have not changed this file in almost a year, and suddenly when doing a build today I get this error message and build fails. Any ideas?

[image]

Tried closing and re-launching Xcode, and tried reboot, same error.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project/cleaning the build folder/deleting Derived Data?

Comment: Yes. Didn't solve it :(

Comment: Are you targetting `iOS`? Why are you using `WatchKit` resources in an `iOS` project, when those are supposed to be used on `watchOS`?

Comment: I have an iOS app that also has a WatchKit app

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to mix UIKit and WatchKit; I don't know how this could ever have compiled, because `UITableViewCell` is not available on watchOS and to the best of my knowledge never has been.

In watchOS, tables are created using `WKInterfaceTable`, and cells are direct subclasses of `NSObject`. When designing your table in IB, change the class of its Table Row Controller to be your custom class and its identifier to something you'll use in code – "Row" or whatever.

Once that's done, you can go ahead and make connections from IB to your custom subclass, and finally tell WatchKit to load as many rows as you need inside your `awake(withContext:)` method:

```
table.setNumberOfRows(10, withRowType: "Row")
```